# Speech to text modification

Tags: java, android-studio, speech-to-text

I’m working on a modified speech to text feature that should take in a users speech and convert it to text but I want the output text to be exactly what the user is saying. This means I want to detect word disfluency’s such as stammers like “sstttop” and “pppplease”. Ive already written a Java program that does the speech to text but I need to know if it’s possible to modify it to detect speech disfluency. Any input and help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's better to improve the structure of the text from the speech delivered by stammer

Comment: How is that an answer to the question?

Answer (score -1):

My first guess would be that you would have to analyze the time that a user spends producing each specific sound. For example, one S could be the 's' sound for half a second whereas two 's's could be represented by the user producing the sound for one second. I understand that this is not completely accurate but best guess I can think of.

Answer (score -1):

As someone who used a lot speech to text apis, What are you looking for is a little bit difficulte to acheive, however, there is a feature that can maybe help you. Depending on the provider you are using, try to look for `custom vocabulary`, it allow you to specify some words to keep in mind when transcribing the audio with a boosting value.

however `Disfluencies`, I believe it's closely related to the provider you are using, some of them will completely remove filler workd like `assembly` except for some values, others like microsoft will give you many transcriptions, some of them with word disfluency's and others not. Please take a look at this link: [microsoft Disfluency removal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/display-text-format?pivots=programming-language-csharp#disfluency-removal)